# Changing Timestamps from tz='UTC' to tz='tzutc()'

Tags: python, timestamp, utc, pytz

I have a series from an API call and it gives me the index in the format

```
timeseries.index.values[0]

>>> Timestamp('2019-10-25 15:33:26.068569856+0000', tz='tzutc()')
```

Then I'm appending some data with the timestamp: `datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)`, which, sadly, has another format

```
timeseries.index.values[-1]

>>> Timestamp('2019-10-25 15:33:27.388853+0000', tz='UTC')]
```

Which will cause some errors down the road. How can I create a timestamp thats in the original format (tz='tzutc())?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.tz import *

datetime.now(tzutc())
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'

Comment: you did not import the right module. included the correct import in the edit